# How to Compare dates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

So I have an array with an x number of dates for example:

```
const dates= [date1, date2, date3, date4,...]
```

Where date1, date2, date3, date4 ... are all in Firebase timestamp date format.
So I wanna be able to first convert each date into the day of the week (monday, tuesday...) and I also want to check if one date repeats, so `(Monday, Tuesday, Monday, Wednesday, Wednesday)`
And if they do repeat id like to get the length of how many times they repeated, and the other ones that don't repeat I also want to get the length of those.
I've tried doing a `forEach`
like so,

```
dates.forEach(el=>{
    const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    console.log(days[el.toDate().getDay()])
})
```

But get stuck here, don't really know how to compare if they are the same day.
EDIT:
I Realized that the date im using is in firebase timestamps

Comment: Looks like you want a reducer. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Are you using a date library? I don't believe `.toDate()` exists in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
var dates = [new Date('03/09/1999'), new Date('12/29/1990')];
const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
  'Saturday', 'Sunday'
]

var daysOfWeek = dates.map(el => {
  return days[el.getDay()];
});

var counts = {};
daysOfWeek.forEach(function(x) {
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
});

// Including the days that do not appear
days.forEach(item => {
   if(!Object.keys(counts).includes(item)) {
     counts[item] = 0;
   }
});

console.log('All days: ', daysOfWeek);
console.log('Repeated times: ', counts);
```

Comment: Thanks, i have one more thing to add, would it be possible to fill add the days that are do not appear to have 0. So like {monday: 2, tuesday: 0, sunday: 1}etc

Comment: Yes it´s possible. I´ve edited my code to do that. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be the simplest way

The daysCount array index will represent each day with the number of days as the value:

```js
const dates = [
  new Date('3/19/21'), // Friday
  new Date('4/12/21'), // Monday
  new Date('4/19/21'), // Monday
];

const daysCount = Array(7).fill(0);

dates.forEach(date => {
  const day = date.getDay();
  daysCount[day] += 1;
});

console.log(daysCount);
```

Comment: The trick with `Array(7)` and array index being the day value is nice 

Comment: Using [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and given the OP has time values, not dates: `dates.reduce((acc, date) => ++acc[new Date(date).getDay()] && acc, Array(7).fill(0));`, which will also work if *date* is a *Date*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG The question says that it needs the day of the week and count them. Do we need to worry about the time values?

Comment: `new Date(date)` will work whether *date* is a Date or time value. You could finish the job by mapping the *daysCount* array to an object of `{dayName:count}`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Date.getDay()` returns 0 for Sunday, not Monday. But better yet, `Intl.DateTimeFormat` can be used to convert dates to day of the week as a string (e.g. `'Monday'`) as opposed to an int.

You're on the right track for iterating your dates, but you want `array.map` instead of `forEach` to map between dates and day of ht week.

You can then use `array.reduce` to count occurrances and `array.sort` to sort by occurances.

You'll see `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` in my snippet; those convert between arrays and objects.

```js
let dates = [new Date('3/19/21'), new Date('4/12/21'), new Date('4/19/21')];

let dayCounts = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(dates
        .map(date =>
                new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {weekday: 'long'}).format(date))
        .reduce((counts, day) => {
            counts[day] = counts[day] || 0;
            counts[day]++;
            return counts;
        }, {}))
        .sort(([day1, count1], [day2, count2]) => count2 - count1));

console.log(dayCounts);
```

Comment: I realized that the date format is actually in firebase timestamp format, so im just getting saturday for all my dates

Answer (score 0):

You could build a frequency map of localized date strings.

```js
// Via: https://www.mockaroo.com/schemas/303013
const data = [{"id":1,"date":"2021-01-07T04:11:42Z"},{"id":2,"date":"2020-04-18T20:51:28Z"},{"id":3,"date":"2020-10-14T16:53:07Z"},{"id":4,"date":"2020-10-02T05:22:21Z"},{"id":5,"date":"2020-11-12T17:21:39Z"},{"id":6,"date":"2020-05-08T14:02:47Z"},{"id":7,"date":"2021-02-04T00:15:57Z"},{"id":8,"date":"2021-02-25T13:55:27Z"},{"id":9,"date":"2020-10-04T12:35:44Z"},{"id":10,"date":"2020-05-06T11:16:12Z"},{"id":11,"date":"2021-02-11T15:36:47Z"},{"id":12,"date":"2020-05-26T09:28:09Z"},{"id":13,"date":"2020-12-20T10:22:44Z"},{"id":14,"date":"2020-06-02T18:44:45Z"},{"id":15,"date":"2021-03-29T15:15:49Z"},{"id":16,"date":"2020-06-04T23:06:55Z"},{"id":17,"date":"2021-01-03T12:22:36Z"},{"id":18,"date":"2020-11-27T19:10:31Z"},{"id":19,"date":"2020-08-30T23:00:25Z"},{"id":20,"date":"2021-03-22T13:50:47Z"}];

const sortByValue = (obj, reverse = false) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort(([ ak, av ], [ bk, bv ]) =>
    (av - bv) * (reverse ? -1 : 1)));

const frequencyMap = data => data.reduce((acc, item) =>
  ({ ...acc, [item]: (acc[item] ?? 0) + 1 }), {});

const
  dates = data.map(({ date }) => date),
  daysOfWeek = dates.map(date => new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' })),
  frequency = sortByValue(frequencyMap(daysOfWeek), true);

console.log(frequency);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```